# Doctrine entity caching?

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have one project which wasn't developed by me. And it has strange behaviour. I added new field to entity, generated setters/getters for this field as usual. After that I updated database schema through `doctrine:schema:update`, but now I see very strange behaviour - symfony throws error `Call to undefined method %my method name%`. I checked again, this method really exists.

After that I cleared a cache through `rm -rf app/cache/*`. The first page loading all works fine. But at second loading I got this error again. So, when I tried to clear cache again, this situation is repeated. When I tried to use get_class_methods(`$myEntity`), it shows new methods after first page loading, but after second - not.

I tried to use commands like `doctrine:cache:clear-*`, but they are useless.

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: There is possibly some caching in the opcache. Restarting the server, or [deleting the cache by php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php) helps.

Comment: No, it didn't help.

By the way, everything works through development mode(app_dev.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem was solved when I restarted php-fpm. Such a mistery.